# how to get the table with merge cells in exactly same format in excel file

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to get the table in same manner from Link in excel file, I am  getting the table by using the code below

```
#Getting particular table from the page and sending to excel file
page    = urllib2.urlopen('http://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html').read()
soup    = BeautifulSoup(page)
a       = soup('div', {'class' : 'col-5'})[0]
with open('android version 2013_01_18.csv', 'wb') as csvfile:
    csvout = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    csvout.writerow(["Version","Codename","API", "Distribution"])
    for table in a.findAll('table'):
        print '#'
        print '# Table'
        print '# Fields: ' + ','.join([tr.text for tr in table.findAll('th')])
        for row in table.findAll('tr'):
            csvout.writerow([tr.text for tr in row.findAll('td')])
```

I am getting output in excel as :

```
1.6 Donut   4   0.20%
2.1 Eclair  7   2.40%
2.2 Froyo   8   9.00%
"2.3 - 2.3.2
"   Gingerbread 9   0.20%
"2.3.3 - 2.3.7
        "   10  47.40%  
3.1 Honeycomb   12  0.40%
3.2 13  1.10%   
4.0.3 - 4.0.4   Ice Cream Sandwich  15  29.10%
4.1 Jelly Bean  16  9.00%
4.2 17  1.20%
```

Here the problem is with the row immediately after merge cells, as td counts are 3 instead of 4
I found that for creating merge cells rowspan=2 has been used in the code, but i want to know how to use this information for getting data exactly same, Below is the HTML structure

```
<tr>
 <td>
 <a href="/about/versions/android-2.3.html">2.3 - 2.3.2</a>
 </td>
 <td rowspan="2">Gingerbread</td>
 <td>9</td>
 <td>0.2%</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>
 <a href="/about/versions/android-2.3.3.html">2.3.3 - 2.3.7 </a>
 </td>
 <td>10</td>
 <td>47.4%</td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

Of the formats that Excel can read, .csv is one of the easiest to generate, but also one of the least powerful. It does not support merging cells (or setting data types for a cell, or having multiple worksheets).

If you are using Excel 2007 or newer, you can write an .xlsx file using [openpyxl](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). Once you have created a worksheet and filled in the data, you can use [merge_cells](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#openpyxl.worksheet.Worksheet.merge_cells) on the worksheet for those cells that have rowspan=X in the original HTML, to get the effect you desire.

If you have an older version of Excel you might want to look at [xlwt](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlwt)